# Spring MVC + Java Config + Embedded Tomcat - Spring Security 3 Not Working

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-security, spring-java-config

Lots of answers around these keywords, but nothing that seems to solve my problem. I'm may not be 'getting it' but currently nothing that I'm understanding from other solutions is working in my particular situation.

Because of a deployment method we're using I'm having to un-Spring Bootify an application which means explicitly setting up Tomcat and dealing with all the little annoyances that Spring Boot looks after for you.

My interesting dependencies for this are:

```
spring (core, etc) 3.2.13.RELEASE
spring-security (core, web, config) 3.2.9.RELEASE
tomcat-embed-core 7.0.67
```

I set up Tomcat in my main method where I also setup all my contexts:

```java
final Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
tomcat.setPort(serverPort);

final Context container = tomcat.addContext(contextRootPath, staticFileDocumentBaseDirectoryAbsolutePathStr);

final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
rootContext.setDisplayName("rootContext");
rootContext.register(CommonBeans.class);
rootContext.register(ApplicationBeans.class);

final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
dispatcherContext.setDisplayName("dispatcherContext");
dispatcherContext.register(MvcConfig.class);
dispatcherContext.scan("app.configuration.controllers");

final DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext);

final Wrapper wrapper = Tomcat.addServlet(container, APPLICATION_NAME, dispatcherServlet);
wrapper.setLoadOnStartup(1);

container.addServletMapping("/", APPLICATION_NAME);
tomcat.start();
```

My MVCConfig class imports the SecurityConfiguration class

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Import({ SecurityBeans.class, SecurityConfiguration.class, ThymeleafConfig.class })
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    addResourceHandlers().......
}
```

And my Security Config is as follows:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier("realAuthProvider")
    private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/images/**", "/js/**", "/fonts/**", "/less/**", "/webjars/**", "/login", "/logout", "/404", "/403", "/formlyHtml/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=bad_credentials")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Now, from this I would expect my controller, that is mapped to "/" would require authentication and Spring Security should redirect to "login", where my nice lovely login page will be displayed, but it doesn't redirect, it just goes straight to the "/" controller, which fires a Null Pointer because an authenticated user in the context doesn't exist.

I've read things around about the SecurityConfig may not be assigned to the correct context, but looking at my main Tomcat setup I thought I would be dealing with this correctly in there. The only mix may be because the Mvc controllers need dependencies autowired from the application beans (CommonBeans and ApplicationBeans), so I need to import those classes after their @Controller annotations.

I also have a class - SpringSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer - residing in the same package as MvcConfig but this doesn't appear to be loaded (but then I don't know what magic is going to be referencing that in my configuration)

Can someone tell me why my Spring Security config doesn't appear to be functioning with my controllers based on what I've got down here?

Thanks

Comment: have you solved this problem? I have the same problem now, and I really don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized Spring security?

You need to create a class that `extends` [AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/context/AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.html).

This loads the springSecurityFilterChain automatically, and registers the `DelegatingFilterProxy` to use the `springSecurityFilterChain` before any other registered Filter (Basically, it will put Spring security "in the way" of your requests):

```
public class SecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {}
```

I would also remove:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
}
```

You already configuring the `authenticationProvider` in the overridden method in your configuration.

See [here](https://github.com/geditdk/spring-web-app/blob/master/src/main/java/uk/co/geditdk/springwebapp/configuration/SecurityConfig.java) for an example.

Comment: your link is returning HTTP 404 page not found